# Tasker App for Photo and Caption to Note

Tags: applications, photos, tasker, automation, notes

I would like a Tasker app that allows me to take a photo, provide a text note like a caption, and then stores both the photo and caption in a note app like Keep, Evernote, or Onenote.

So far, I have a Tasker task with 3 actions: Variable Set (for the photo's filename), Take Photo (which takes the photo and sets the photo's filename), and Variable Query (for the caption). The issue I run into is getting the photo and caption into a note app. Is this done with the intent or share action? Can I get both the photo and text to be stored at the same time? Thanks.